# How to use curl to post xml data to a simple server

Tags: curl, go, restful-url

I'm trying out go-restful. I found an example here: [go example](https://github.com/emicklei/go-restful/blob/master/examples/restful-resource-functions.go)

I try to use curl to post data:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: text/xml"  -X POST -d "<Product><Id>1</Id><Title>The First</Title></Product>" localhost:8080/products
```

but it didn't work. My questions are:

1. how to use curl to post data in this example ?
2. how can this program read xml data into a struct using ?

   err := req.ReadEntity(updatedProduct)

(In other examples, req.ReadEntity is able to read json data. How can this single function read data into different structs?)

thanks:)

Comment: What does "didn't work" exactly mean

Comment: I got the error message: 415: Unsupported Media Type. I thought this program allow us to post data:)

Answer (score 1):

This library doesnt recognize `text/xml` header for some reason, you should use `application/xml`

[Check the source code](https://github.com/emicklei/go-restful/blob/7dd77babc0fbac18c02f6968b4dcf69e9c43bc73/constants.go#L8)

```
const (
    MIME_XML   = "application/xml"      
.....
```

Here is the difference [rfc3023](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3023.txt):

> If an XML document -- that is, the unprocessed, source XML document --
>   is readable by casual users, text/xml is preferable to
>   application/xml. MIME user agents (and web user agents) that do not
>   have explicit support for text/xml will treat it as text/plain, for
>   example, by displaying the XML MIME entity as plain text.
>   Application/xml is preferable when the XML MIME entity is unreadable
>   by casual users.

Comment: its defined here https://github.com/emicklei/go-restful/blob/1905f349c059305e2785c36f986dbaf9e691898c/entity_accessors.go#L37